# выпрыгивает ошибка QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1

Tags: qt, qpainter

Пытаюсь рисовать мышкой но почемото выпрыгивает ошибка

вот весь код:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this); // Создаём объект отрисовщика

     float rad = 1;

     QPointF pt = event->localPos(); // event->Pos() и так и так пробовал
     QPen pen_abris(Qt::black, 2, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::FlatCap); 

     painter.setPen(pen_abris);
     painter.drawEllipse(pt.x()-rad, pt.y()-rad, rad*2.0, rad*2.0);
     this->update();
 }
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPen>
#include <QFont>
#include <QFontMetrics>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QRegion>
#include <QPointF>
#include <QGraphicsView>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
     MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

     QPoint pos; //координаты точки для рисования
protected:

     void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

вот ошибка

QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active

Почему то не отрисовывает , не могу понять (фон задавал)

Comment: Посмотри здесь - https://forum.qt.io/topic/64693/unable-to-paint-on-qt-widget-shows-error-paintengine-should-no-longer-be-called/3

Comment: @PavelParshin спасибо

Answer (score -1, accepted):

в общем  узнал что вся от рисовка ведется только в функции

```
paintEvent
```

Теперь код выглядит так (также я напортачил и выводится только одна точка стоит передать в массив и можно будет рисовать)

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    float rad = 1;

    QPainter painter(this); // Создаём объект отрисовщика
    QPen pen_abris(Qt::black, 2, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::FlatCap); // кисть обрисовки (компаса)
    painter.setPen(pen_abris);
    painter.drawEllipse(30, 30, 2, 2);
    painter.drawEllipse(this->pos.x()-rad, this->pos.y()-rad, rad*2.0, rad*2.0);

}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
     float rad = 1;
     this->pos = event->pos(); //положение курсора мыш
     this->update();
 }
```

класс мейн виндовс

```
...
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
     MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

     QPoint pos; //координаты точки для рисования

 protected:
     void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

     void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
};
...
```